# Error installing Pyperclip in Python

Tags: python, pyperclip

I'm getting an error installing Pyperclip for Python:

- Windows OS 64-bit: 7
- Python version: 3.6.1

Changed directories to scripts tried attempts like this:

```
pip.exe install pyperclip

python -m pip install pyperclip
```

[image: Error]

I'm getting a problem confirming the SSL certificate.

Comment: Please post your error message as text, not as an image. The blurry dark red text on black background is hardly readable, and I'm not willing to try and decipher it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may have been a transient error on the website, because I can install it just fine.

```
E:\Python36\Scripts>pip install pyperclip
Collecting pyperclip
  Downloading pyperclip-1.5.27.zip
Installing collected packages: pyperclip
  Running setup.py install for pyperclip ... done
Successfully installed pyperclip-1.5.27
```

Comment: I'm new to python. How do I fix a transient error. Do I need to try to redownload it from the website again? And try the previous steps. Thank you.

Comment: If I'm right about it being a transient error, it is nothing you can fix, because the problem is with the website and not with what you are doing. I would just try again. If you still get that error, try pasting the web address `https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyperclip/` into a browser address bar and see what happens. If the problem persists then maybe the browser will give you a more helpful message.